# I cannot see Cathegory list admin, How to fix that

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-admin

I registred Category admin in models.py. I added that model in Post model via ForenKey. But when i log into admin console i cannot see my Categories, I just see Category Object(1), Category Object(2) and so on.
I will provide you a print screen and a code.

http://prntscr.com/nxt25y

instead if Japanese Kitchen or any other category (im working blog for chef),
i see Category Object, the one that i highlighted on printscreen.
I think its not a big deal but i didnt worked on django for quite some time so i forgot a lot.
Can you spot a mistake?

Thanks guys

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.text import slugify
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'catergory'
        verbose_name_plural = 'catergories'

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(
        help_text="A short label, generally used in URLs.", default='', max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='New category')
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    content = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_posted']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

this is admin.py

```
from .models import Post, Category
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin
from suit_ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget


class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'name': CKEditorWidget(editor_options={'startupFocus': True})
        }


class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'slug')
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}


admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)


class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PostForm
    list_display = ['title', 'slug', 'date_posted', 'author']
    list_filter = ['title', 'date_posted']

    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}


admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

Comment: You've indented  `def __str__(self):` too far in the Category model.  Make the indentation the same as `class Meta:`

Comment: Hahahaha, what a mistake....Thanks a lot man!!! <3

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `__str__` method in your models to handle what you intend to display on admin.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'catergory'
        verbose_name_plural = 'catergories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```